# how to eliminate extraneous console output after ctrl-c in Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, windows-console

When pressing Ctrl-c there is almost always additional output.  I'd like to ensure that after receiving the Ctrl-c the program doesn't show anything other than possibly "^C".

I found what is mostly the same question but, it was for Linux and my attempts to "port" the solution from Linux to Windows have not succeeded.

At this point, I'm out of things to try and can use some help, which I will definitely appreciate.  Thank you.

The short example program below suffers from that problem.

```
{$APPTYPE        CONSOLE}

program _SetConsoleCtrlHandler;

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils
  ;

function CtrlHandler(CtrlType : DWORD) : BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  result := FALSE;

  case CtrlType of
    CTRL_C_EVENT,
    CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
    begin
      result := TRUE;

      ExitProcess(7);
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  s : shortstring;

begin
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@CtrlHandler, TRUE);

  while TRUE do
  begin
    write('press <ctrl-c> to end this program : ');
    readln(s);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Besides my answer below, you shouldn't be looping after the readln.  You are either creating a single threaded app that executes from top to bottom until you detect Ctrl-C and immediately exit or an app where all other work is done in a thread and you are waiting for Ctrl-C in the main app thread.

Comment: CtrlHandler runs in a different thread

Comment: Your problem identification does not seem to be correct. E.g. empty your loop (`while true do;`) then press ctrl+c and see if there's any extraneous output.

Comment: I finally figured out what the problem is.  Without a call to Sleep after the readln, the loop gets to execute the writeln before the ctrl-c handler can execute the call to ExitProcess.  That's what causes the additional characters to show.  In the sample code I posted, simply add a call "Sleep(5)" after the readln and the extraneous character problem is gone.

Comment: @ScienceAmatuer That's not really a reliable approach because you cannot guarantee the timing of the signal that Ctrl-C was pressed.  Like I said below, you really need to structure your exit process to wait on the ctrl-c.

Comment: @ Allen, the application cannot be waiting for a ctrl-c.  It has to process user input and to do that it has to display an appropriate prompt and readln whatever the user typed.

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do this is to have a separate unit that is signaled and a simple wait, like the following.  In the main console project you call WaitForCtrlC instead of Readln().  You could also use a TEvent and wait on the event instead of looping, like I show in this example:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF LINUX}
  Posix.Signal,
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows,
  {$ENDIF}
  SysUtils;

procedure WaitForCtrlC;

implementation

var
  Control_C: Boolean = False;

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function ConsoleCtrlHandler(dwCtrlType: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  if (dwCtrlType = CTRL_C_EVENT) then
    Control_C := True;
  Result := True;
end;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF LINUX}
var
  sigIntHandler: sigaction_t;

procedure SigHandler(SigNum: Integer); cdecl;
begin
  Control_C := True;
end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure WaitForCtrlC;
begin
  while not Control_C do
    Sleep(25);
end;

initialization
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@ConsoleCtrlHandler, True);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF LINUX}
  sigIntHandler._u.sa_handler := @SigHandler;
  sigemptyset(sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
  sigIntHandler.sa_flags := 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, @sigIntHandler, nil);
  {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: @ Allen, thank you for your help.  The problem isn't the readln,  Adding a Sleep(5) - or even Sleep (1) - after the readln, solves the problem in the sample code I posted.   It seems that once ctrl-c has been pressed, there is a race condition.  Without the Sleep(xx) the loop has enough time to execute again before the call to ExitProcess is made.  Just FYI, I up voted your answer but, I won't check it as the answer because the real answer is to somehow (usually with a call to sleep) give enough time for the control handler to execute the call to ExitProcess/TerminateProcess..

Comment: I think the main point here is you shouldn't be using Readln() if your intent is to shutdown your app with Ctrl-C.  If you do it by waiting for Ctrl-C the problem you describe goes away.

Comment: @ Allen, the readln is necessary. In the typical command line interpreter there is the combination write <prompt> followed by readln <command>.  There is nothing wrong with using writeln and readln.  The problem is to ensure that the ctrl-c handler always wins the execute race by introducing a delay in the loop.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur Neither your question nor your example discuss that intent at all.  Your example only shows you wanting to exit your program when you press Ctlr-C.

Comment: @ Allen, I made the example as simple as possible for illustrative purposes.  I might have made it a bit too simple.